# Image on header_frame displaying only in the first page of a pdf generated by xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, xhtml2pdf

I'm developing a web app using python 2.7 with Flask. I'm using xhtml2pdf to generate a pdf based on a template with Jinja2.
I want to put an image on the header_frame of the template, but it's only showing on the first page.
I tried doing it with text, and it works, the header is shown on all the pages.

Here's the view code:

```
@report.route('/commissionist/<period>/<commissionist_id>')
@login_required
def commissionist_report(period, commissionist_id):
    period_d = periods.Period(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(strptime(period, '%m-%Y'))))
    carga = load_model.get_commissionist_load(period_d, commissionist_id)

    resp = create_pdf(render_template('report/report.html', commissionist_load=carga, period=period, period_datetime=period_d.to_datetime()))
    response = make_response(resp)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=Informe '+carga.commissionist.name+'.pdf'

    return response
```

Here's the create_pdf function:

```
def create_pdf(pdf_data):
    pdf = StringIO()
    pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(pdf_data), pdf)
    resp = pdf.getvalue()
    pdf.close()
    return resp
```

And here's the template (the important part):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Informe</title>
        {% block extra_css %}
            <style>
                @page {
                    size: letter portrait;
                    @frame header_frame {           /* Static Frame */
                    -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
                    left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 50pt;
                    }
                    @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
                    left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 110pt; height: 632pt;
                    }
                    @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
                    -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
                    left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
                    }
                }
            </style>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block body %}
        <div id="header_content">
            <img src="path\to\file.png" width="25%">
        </div>
        <div id="footer_content">Página <pdf:pagenumber/>
            de <pdf:pagecount/>
        </div>

        <!--The rest of the html-->

    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: I don't remember what I ended up doing, I stopped working at that project long ago, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same trouble at this week, we had some updates on `python` and `xhtml2pdf` but after 2 hours trying I solved it out.

I'm using `xhtml2pdf => 0.2.4` and `Python => 3.7`

The solution:

I created one generic method to create pdf such as you:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from io import StringIO

...

def pdf_converter(self,html):

    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(html))
    return pisaStatus.dest
```

Then on view:

```
@my_bp.route('/...my_root...')
@roles_required('admin')
def export_pdf():
    from xxxx.utils.export_pdf import ExportPDF
    a = ExportPDF()
    pdf = a.pdf_converter(...my_method_that_creates_html...)

    pdf.seek(0)

    return send_file(pdf, attachment_filename="Report_xxxx.pdf", as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: how are you imported send_file method?